# How to type a function that formats snake case to camel case?

Tags: typescript

```
type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}`
  ? `${Lowercase<T>}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}`
  : S;

const snakeToCamelCase = <T extends string>(subject: T): SnakeToCamelCase<T> => {
  return subject.replace(/([_-][a-z])/gi, (segment) => {
    return segment.toUpperCase().replace('-', '').replace('_', '');
  });
};
```

as is, the above code produces error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SnakeToCamelCase<T>'.
```

https://tsplay.dev/w2KAVN

What's the correct way to type `snakeToCamelCase` function?

Comment: The compiler cannot possibly understand that `segment.toUpperCase()..etc.etc()` turns a `T` into a `SnakeCamelCase<T>` so you'll need to tell it.  Just use `as any` or something in your return statement like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvdRW).

Comment: Most likely related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69668850/368691