# How to construct Record using a computed typed?

Tags: typescript

In this code example:

```
const refName = <T extends keyof SegmentEventMap>(subject: T): RefName<T> => {
  return `${snakeToCamelCase(subject)}Ref`;
};

const useViewedEventTwo = <EventName extends keyof SegmentEventMap>(event: EventName): Record<RefName<EventName>, string> => {
  return {
    [refName(event)]: ''
  };
}
```

- `refName` produces result of type `RefName<T>`
- `useViewedEventTwo` expects a result in shape of `Record<RefName<EventName>, string>`

Here `{ [refName(event)]: '' }` should satisfy that condition. However, instead, [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) sees it as `{ [x: number]: string; }`.

https://tsplay.dev/mbdY8w

How do I cast `refName(event)` name so that it satisfies the expectation of the `Record<RefName<EventName>, string>`?

Comment: Question title might need a rework. Not sure how to phrase the question.

Comment: this is [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) so just do `{
   [refName(event)]: '' } as any` (or `as Record<...>`) if you want to cast something, since computed keys will get widened to `string` no matter what.